# How to hide HTML output when JavaScript object is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm displaying a series of objects. Sometimes, I will run into a situation where an object will be empty. How can I ensure the HTML markup doesn't display on the page, when the object is empty?

```js
var eventList = [
  {
    header: "Main Header One",
    title: "This is Title One",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat enim laborum ullam officia sed deleniti libero tempora maxime nulla cum, modi labore ex repudiandae similique.",
    link: "google",
    linkText: "Google"
  },
  {
    //no data in this object. I don't want the card to display at all if there's no data.
    header: "",
    title: "",
    text: "",
    link: "",
    linkText: ""
  },
  {
    header: "Main Header One",
    title: "This is Title One",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat enim laborum ullam officia sed deleniti libero tempora maxime nulla cum, modi labore ex repudiandae similique.",
    link: "yahoo",
    linkText: "Yahoo"
  }  
];


//View
$.each(eventList, function(key, value) {
  $('.list').append(
    `<div class="card mb-3">` +
      `<h5 class="card-header">` + value.header + `</h5>` +
      `<div class="card-body">` +
        `<h6 class="card-title">`  + value.title + `</h6>` +
        `<p class="card-text">` + value.text + `</p>` +
      `</div>` +
      `<div class="card-footer">` +
        `<a href="https://` + value.link + `.com">` + value.linkText + `</a>` +
      `</div>` +
    `</div>`
  );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="list"><div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So add a check that it is empty.....

Comment: I've done that.

Comment: Complaining about downvotes normally brings more downvotes. Who cares about the votes, you got an answer.

Comment: it's not one of the best codes I've seen ( I din't downvote, but shame on you)

Comment: FYI the reason why you use template literal strings is no not have the `+` signs all over. So your use of them is wrong. `\`<div><h1>${value.header}</h1></div>\``

Comment: I apologize for the whining.

Comment: If you're going to use template literals, you should look up how to use them correctly. [Here's the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @epascarello - Just thought I'd follow up here. As self-punishment for my griping, I've rebuilt the above using template literals correctly. Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/WVbLLo). Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//View
$.each(eventList, function(key, value) {
    if(value.header != "")
    {
     $('.list').append(
    `<div class="card mb-3">` +
      `<h5 class="card-header">` + value.header + `</h5>` +
      `<div class="card-body">` +
        `<h6 class="card-title">`  + value.title + `</h6>` +
        `<p class="card-text">` + value.text + `</p>` +
      `</div>` +
      `<div class="card-footer">` +
        `<a href="https://` + value.link + `.com">` + value.linkText + `</a>` +
      `</div>` +
    `</div>`
    );
    }
});
```

Comment: I rebuilt this using template literals. It's coded better and uses literals correctly. [codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/WVbLLo)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter the data and remove object which contains empty string, then you can use `$.each`

```js
var eventList = [{
    header: "Main Header One",
    title: "This is Title One",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat enim laborum ullam officia sed deleniti libero tempora maxime nulla cum, modi labore ex repudiandae similique.",
    link: "google",
    linkText: "Google"
  },
  {
    //no data in this object. I don't want the card to display at all if there's no data.
    header: "",
    title: "",
    text: "",
    link: "",
    linkText: ""
  },
  {
    header: "Main Header One",
    title: "This is Title One",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat enim laborum ullam officia sed deleniti libero tempora maxime nulla cum, modi labore ex repudiandae similique.",
    link: "yahoo",
    linkText: "Yahoo"
  }
];

let dataArr = $.grep(eventList, function(n, i) {
  return (n.header !== "" &&
    n.title !== "" &&
    n.text !== "" &&
    n.link !== "" &&
    n.linkText !== ""
  );
});
$.each(dataArr, function(key, value) {

  $('.list').append(
    `<div class="card mb-3">` +
    `<h5 class="card-header">` + value.header + `</h5>` +
    `<div class="card-body">` +
    `<h6 class="card-title">` + value.title + `</h6>` +
    `<p class="card-text">` + value.text + `</p>` +
    `</div>` +
    `<div class="card-footer">` +
    `<a href="https://` + value.link + `.com">` + value.linkText + `</a>` +
    `</div>` +
    `</div>`
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='list'></div>
```